# retrieve email and automatically import its contents into an sql table

Tags: sql-server, email, batch-file

I have a .bat file that sends an email.  I want our mail server to read the email and import its contents directly into an sql table.  I know I can write script to have the file import directly into an sql table but I'm working on a government server that won't allow us to talk to the sql server so to bypass that I came up with the email option.  Has anyone ever done this and if so what script did you use?

Comment: Not sure what your question is here.  You said you know how to dump the email to a sql table (seems to address your question).  You also take about trying to dupe a government server (sounds like a bad idea).  What "script" are you looking for?

Comment: OP means to import the .bat file contents without emailing it. Once it is emailed OP doesn't know what to do.

Comment: Earl, I don't know how to dump the email to a sql table automatically.  I know how to create a .bat file to auto import into a sql table but am restricted of doing so because of server policies.  My workaround is to send an email out from the restricted server.  So since I have it in email form, I want to auto read the contents from the email and import into sql